# Php create class function to retrieve data from table

Tags: php, class, function

I'm new learner in php OOP, I want to create a class function to get register users info, how can I do that?

```
class Functions{

    public static function getUserInfo($user_id){
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE user_id='".$user_id."'");
        $rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

        if(mysql_num_rows($sql) >= 1){
            return $rows;
        }
    }
}
```

to echo user's info:

```
$user = new Functions();
$user->getUserInfo($_SESSION['user_id']);

echo $user->user_email;
```

I got nuthing output with 'undefined property' message, what is the proper way to create function to retrieve user's info? thanks.

Comment: Do not use the `mysql_*` family of functions unless you have to. They are obsolete. Look at mysqli or PDO instead. The only exception to this is if your PHP installation does not support any of the newer alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe that?

```
class Functions{

    public static function getUserInfo($user_id){
        if(empty($user_id)) {
            return null;
        }
        // connect to db
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE user_id='".$user_id."' LIMIT 1");

        if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){
                $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_ASSOC);
                // close connection to db
                return $row;
        }
        // close connection to db
        return null;
    }
}

$userID = !empty($_SESSION['user_id']) ? (int)$_SESSION['user_id'] : null;
$user = Functions::getUserInfo($userID);
if($user !== null) {
    echo $user['user_email'];
}
```

This is ony example, use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` to manage data in database.

Comment: I still cannot see the output, how could I echo info similar like `$userData->user_email`?

Comment: I could see the data now, but I still doubt on how to use something like `$userData->user_email`? to output the results?

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_array returns array, not object. 
$user['user_email'] should work.

In general as you mentioned OOP I would say your code is using classes, but it is not OOP (if I understand correctly how you're going to structure it). What you do is simply wrapping procedural code into a class. 
With OOP you need to structure code such a way that it has self-contained objects, so creating "Functions" class containing various utility methods is generally a bad idea. Consider e.g. creating User object instead.

For database abstraction I would recommend checking PDO (http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php).